# ActiveRecord custom validadion error not preserved when building relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, model

I have models:

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  SPECIALIZATIONS_LIMIT = 5

  has_many :specializations
  has_many :cruise_lines, through: :specializations

  validate :validate_specializations_limit

  protected
    def validate_specializations_limit
      errors.add(:base, "Agency specializations limit is #{SPECIALIZATIONS_LIMIT}.") if specializations.count > SPECIALIZATIONS_LIMIT
    end
end

class CruiseLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :specializations
  has_many :agencies, through: :specializations
end

class Specialization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency, inverse_of: :specializations
  belongs_to :cruise_line, inverse_of: :specializations
end
```

In my service I try to save agency and specialization relations like this:

```
attributes = params.require(:agency).permit(
  :name, :website, :description, :booking_email, :booking_phone, 
  :optional_booking_phone, :working_hours, :cruise_line_ids => []
)

agency.update_attributes(attributes)

attributes[:cruise_line_ids].select{|x| x.to_i > 0}.each do |cruise_line_id|
  agency.specializations.build(cruise_line_id: cruise_line_id)
end
```

How this code works:

1) it updates attributes;

2) it saves relations and updates them if I deselect some checkboxes with cruise lines;

**3) in case I enter incorrect data or select too many cruise line checkboxes, it does not save data, but also shows no errors!**

If I add some inspect code `puts agency.errors.inspect` immediately AFTER the block that builds relations - it works exactly as I expect: if everything saved - shows success message, if validation errors occured - shows error messages.

QUESTION:

why adding `puts agency.errors.inspect` immediately after saving code makes everything work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found bug: it was in my controller, that made redirect to edit page always after storing method worked (even if model was not saved!). Controller code looks like this:

```
if AgencyService.update_agency(current_agent.agency, params)
  flash[:success] = "Agency data updated successfully"
  redirect_to action: :edit
else
  render :edit
end
```

The only thing I had to do was to add this code to the end of my `update_agency` method

```
  # ... build relations
  return false if agency.errors.present?
  true
end
```

So if my `AgencyService.update_agency` return false - user is not redirected and all errors are shown on the page :)